# How to make a column of count of rows of different value in KQL?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Assume we have a table like this:

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| A | 1 |

I would like to expand the table with a third column, counting the number of "Name" belonging to that row, with Value=1

| Name | Value | expand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 (there are 2 rows of Name=A and Value = 1) |
| A | 0 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 1 (there is 1 row of Name = B and Value = 1) |
| A | 0 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 2 |

Thanks :)

Comment: B1 appears twice

Comment: Why do you need the raw data? Why not aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you the number of occurrences for each combination of `Name` and `Value`.

You could either use that as-is, or `join` it back with the raw data, if necessary.

```
datatable(Name:string, Value:int)
[
    "A", 1,
    "A", 0,
    "B", 1,
    "A", 0,
    "B", 1,
    "A", 1,
]
| summarize count() by Name, Value
```

| Name | Value | count_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| A | 0 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 2 |